# Bluetooth headset mutes audio when mic is enabled

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth, microphone

**Headset model**

Sony WH-1000-XM2 (tested with Jabra Elite 75t as well with same symptoms)

**Bluetooth receiver**

[Ubit-AX200 802.11AX WiFi 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Y2MYK4N) using the drivers found [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29538/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-for-Windows-10?product=189347)

**Sound card**

The onboard card in this motherboard is a [GIGABYTE B550M DS3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550M-DS3H-rev-10) and the drivers are from [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) (Realtek HD Audio Driver (Note) Win10 ver.2004 supported. -- [6‎.0.8945.1] -- 2‎020/05/08)

**OS**

[image: Windows 10 Pro 2004]

**Symptoms**

I can pair the device like normal, no issues. Once paired, playing audio over something like Spotify works fine, playing games mostly works fine (Apex Legends has no audio at all -- not sure if this is related) UNLESS I enable the microphone. If the microphone is enabled, all sound stops (Spotify, games, whatever).

My simple test case is to play some music on Spotify then open sound settings (right-click the sound icon). This is what I see:

[image: Sound settings]

I think click `Device properties and test microphone`. On the next screen if i click `Start test` I can see the microphone receiving input but all music stops playing. It doesn't pause the music, Spotify continues to progress on the song it's on, just the audio output stops. No sound from the headphones.

This happens in online games. If I enable the microphone, game audio stops as well.

Back in the sound settings screen, if i switch the input to anything else, audio is fine as long as the mic is either disabled or a different mic is selected.

In the sound settings found via the Control Panel, I see this:

[image: Control panel sound]

As in the image, if the Headphones entry is set as the default device, all the symptoms above occur. If i switch the default device to Headset, everything starts working as expected (audio and mic work simultaneously). The problem is that the Headset devices is limited to `1 channel, 16 bit, 16000 Hz (Tape Recorder Quality)`:

[image: Headset options]

**What I've tried**

I've mostly tried re-installing drivers and using different combinations of default devices. Setting Headphones as the default device and Headset as the default communication device has no effect.

I don't have easy access to a wired headset with a microphone so I haven't been able to test that way to rule out/in bluetooth as the issue. I'll update if/when I am able to test this. It does happen with both bluetooth headsets that I have so I don't believe it's a headset specific issue.

Comment: I answered your question about whether bluetooth is the root of the issue and if it is headset specific but @DavidPostill♦ deleted my answer.  The answer is that bluetooth is the cause and it isn't headset specific. Below are some sources.  

 https://audeze.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018651652-Notes-on-Bluetooth-quality-for-gaming-video-and-microphone-use

https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/

Comment: I've run into and solved this exact issue before, but for the life of me cannot remember how at the moment. Did you try toggling one of the options that mention "exclusive control"?

Comment: While Exclusive Control or another setting to Mute All Other Applications are both Windows sound settings that can cause the same symptoms, the underlying Bluetooth limitation I cited will still be a problem.  In other words, those two sound settings could solve a similar problem for non-bluetooth sets

Comment: @Arctiic the issue was definitely just how bluetooth works (as the link rfii provided points out). When the mic is enabled, bluetooth uses one channel for the mic and one channel for the audio. Windows does a bad job of switching to the one channel audio device automatically when the mic is in use. MacOS does a much better job of this (as well as mobile devices). This is why wireless gaming headsets often use 2.4ghz wifi type signals to do wireless audio instead of using bluetooth.

Comment: @rfii you are 100% correct. If you put an answer in again that doesn't get deleted, I'll mark it as solved. Bluetooth is just bad for gaming because of the 2 channel limitation and other latency issues. I've since picked up non-bluetooth headset. With bluetooth as-is, it's just not viable for this right now.

Comment: thanks @gregghz, I reposted.  Hopefully he doesn't delete it again.

Comment: @rfii Apologies I didn't catch that my first glance over, now that you mention that I do recall that it was around the time I bought a wired mic that the issue was "resolved" haha.

Comment: @Arctiic, no worries I think it's good info and context as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your bluetooth device is showing up as two audio devices to windows but your headset can only play the output one of these virtual devices at a time. Normally the high quality one is active in the actual physical headset, but as soon as activity is detected on the low quality one or the mic, then the high quality output shuts off and the headset switches. So you need to move the output of the game to the low quality output which may be called handsfree possibly by temporarily disabling that one or selecting the output in "app volume and device preferences" in sound settings.

https://audeze.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018651652-Notes-on-Bluetooth-quality-for-gaming-video-and-microphone-use

https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/

Hope I am wrong though bc it sucks!

Comment: OK thanks for the apologies. Can you undelete superuser.com/q/1566378/1199304 which is even clearer case?

Comment: I am asking about the other related question for which I posted only one answer that you deleted:  superuser.com/q/1566378/1199304

Comment: Right. Well there is a different thing going on here. You are posting the **same** answer to **2 different questions**. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/close-questions) or, ...

Comment: .. if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answers to the questions and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Two questions can have the same answer.  1+4 = 5 and 2+3 = 5.  Having the same answer doesn't mean they're the same question...  You don't even believe it's a duplicate because you haven't closed the other question.  I cannot tailor the answer because you deleted it...  I'd appreciate your help tailoring it because it seems pretty short and direct.

Comment: Well it's answering a different question. So it must be possible to make the answer fit the question. 1. "Bluetooth headset mutes audio when mic is enabled" 2. "My bluetooth headphones will only provide output from one program at a time". So 1 ask about the mic, 2 asks about output from multiple programs (it should be input but the question is badly written).

Comment: Question 2 is correct in saying "output"; input would be a mic, so it would be incorrect to relabel as you said.  Anyway, I rewrote the answer putting the prescribed actions closer to the top albeit it makes a little less sense now in my mind since the background cause of it is now explained later.

Comment: Much better, I have undeleted it. Please think about what we have discussed when answering similar questions in future. Thanks.

Comment: OK all I did was move one statement up by one sentence.  Everything else is pretty much synonym replacement.  Hope you think about this as well.  Thanks

Comment: `"Hope I am wrong though bc it sucks!"` Huge understatement. The low-quality mode is truly awful. It doesn't even have stereo support and is useless for things like gaming or music production.

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, I had to (on Zoom) select Jabra EVOLVE 65 Hands-Free AG Audio (for both microphone and speaker) and NOT Jabra EVOLVE 65 Stereo.

Answer (score 0):

Have tested this on multiple computers, with Windows 10 and Bluetooth 4 as well as 5, with Sony WH-1000XM4, Apple Airpods Pro, Apple Airpods Max, and cheap headphones too.  As soon as you select Mic, the headphones switch to Hands-Free AG Audio and sound from other applications stops while sound into headphones goes to AG Audio (poor quality.)  So it works, both mic and sound, but at mono quality.

Of course if the device is a laptop you can use the laptop's mic, and use the bluetooth headphones in stereo for listening only.

I take all those headphones and connect them to my new desktop computer running Windows 11, and ALL of them work fine.  Sound plays in Stereo, music keeps playing while in chat (Discord/Teams, etc.) if I want, and mic works perfectly fine too.  THIS is what I wanted, but cannot do on any other device not running Windows 11.  There is not even an Hands-Free AG Audio setting I can select on this machine.

While there are many variables in play here beyond the OS, the fact is in Windows 11 it works while NOTHING I have done in Windows 10 gets it to.  Your mileage may vary, but this is what I see.

Comment: 3 times the same answer to differennt questions!

Comment: Windows 11 appears to hide the lower quality hands-free output device and automatically switches to it when the hands-free microphone is in use. This means sound will keep playing (you'll be able to hear discord/game/whatever without manually switching devices). Unfortunately, it's still using the lower quality output so it sounds like trash.