# Bluetooth headset no longer available as output device and input device simultaneously

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, bluetooth, microphone

I have a Jabra Evolve 65, which has served me very well for many years. However, it recently developed a curious behavior: it cannot be simultaneously selected as the input device and the output device.

This means that, e.g., on a Zoom call, I can either use the microphone on the headset and play the audio through external speakers, or I can use another microphone (e.g., my laptop's built-in microphone) and play the audio through my headset earpiece.

I tried all the typical solutions, including unpairing and pairing, uninstalling and re-installing the device, ensuring I had the latest drivers, etc. No change in behavior. I eventually tried re-setting my laptop, a Lenovo Flex 5, back to factory defaults--and that fixed it. I was able to pair the headset and it worked flawlessly as both input and output device.

For two weeks.

After that, the old behavior came back. The only software I've installed is browsers (Chrome and Firefox), print drivers (Lexmark and Brother), Adobe Acrobat, Paint.net, and PDF 24. I've reviewed my Windows updates, and the most recent update was installed Nov 24, but my headset was working fine through Dec 1.

I'm not sure where to look next to get the headset working again. Notably, this same headset works fine when paired with other devices (e.g., with my phone, and with other laptops).

[Possibly related question.](https://superuser.com/questions/1572978/bluetooth-headset-mutes-audio-when-mic-is-enabled)